# Privileges to database tables created by Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am creating a web application using python-Django and mysql. While migrating database framework created following 10 tables.so, is there need to give privileges for those tables to database user ? if yes, which are those ?

```
auth_group
auth_group_permissions
auth_permission
auth_user
auth_user_groups
auth_user_user_permissions
django_admin_log
django_content_type
django_migrations
django_session
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django can create those tables because the user has enough privilege to the database. The tables created from migrations also have sufficient privilege for the user. You don't have to worry about adding privilege to them.

**Update:** From OP's comment, he initially used the root user and then changed the user in Django settings. So he does have to update the privilege for the new user.

Comment: i had done migration using root as default database user and now I have removed root user and using newly created user. So it can cause problem while accessing those tables. Thats why i wanted to know about those privileges.

Comment: Then it's not the same user. If you change user like that, then it will likey cause issues.

Comment: Thats why I am asking for those privileges.

Comment: You didn't mention you changed the user in the Django database setting. So I didn't understand.

Comment: Yes. So which are those privileges I have to update..??

Comment: The CRUD ones to begin with

Comment: Ok, I will try that one. Thank You